# Reset image for multiple buttons when switching between tabs

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have a screen where i have made buttons to look like checkbox with images (`checked.png` and `unchecked.png`). When i switch between tabs, i should reset all the `checkboxes(buttons)` with `unchecked.png`.
 I have done something like this

```
self->eatbuffet = NO;
self->eatnonveg = NO;
self->eatalcohol = NO;



if (eatbuffet == NO || eatnonveg == NO  || eatalcohol == NO) {

    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"un_checked"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
```

And all three are bool values. 
If i check one and switch tabs, its working. But if i do the same with 2 or 3, its not working.
Please Help.

Comment: What I understand here is that you only change 1 button image. Is that what you wanted to do ?

Comment: No, I should reset all buttons. I know that i need to add some extra code also, but no idea about that

Comment: do you have outlets (reference s) for all the 3 buttons?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little idea that might help you:

```
/*
 this method is called everytime your view is going to be shown.
 if your application is based on a tab view controller for example,
 this method will get called every time you go back to that view
*/
-(void) viewWillAppear {
    [super viewWillAppear];
    self.eatbuffet = NO;
    self.eatnonveg = NO;
    self.eatalcohol = NO;

    [button1 setImage[UIImage imageNamed:@"un_checked"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button2 setImage[UIImage imageNamed:@"un_checked"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button3 setImage[UIImage imageNamed:@"un_checked"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.

```
-(void)checkBox:(UIButton*)button{

switch (button.tag) {
    case 0:{
        eatbuffet = button;
        [eatbuffet setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"check"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [eatnonveg setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [eatalcohol setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
        break;
    case 1:
    {
        eatnonveg = button;
        [eatbuffet setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [eatnonveg setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"check"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [eatalcohol setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
        break;
    case 2:
    {
        eatalcohol = button;

        [eatbuffet setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [eatnonveg setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [eatalcohol setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"check"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
        break;

    default:
        break;
}
```

}

Note: you have to set tag 0,1,2.... for all button.

Answer (score 0):

Just put two different images for two states ie: selected and default.. The image will be changed when button changes its state.

```
self.myButton.selected = YES/NO;
```